# Error with Pusher while publishing content in Laravel 9 PHP 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I'm currently updating a `Qr` online platform using `Pusher` in `Laravel 9.52` and `PHP 8.1.10`.

I have an issue with the confirmation of my Qr code when they're scanned here's the `laravel.log` line

`"exception":"[object] (Pusher\\ApiErrorException(code: 0): cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api-.pusher.com ... at /public/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php:782`

Here's the lines in `Pusher.php`

```
public function trigger($channels, string $event, $data, array $params = [], bool $already_encoded = false): object
{
    $post_value = $this->make_trigger_body($channels, $event, $data, $params, $already_encoded);
    $this->log('trigger POST: {post_value}', compact('post_value'));
    return $this->process_trigger_result($this->post('/events', $post_value)); (the exception is pointing here)
}
```

We're using `"pusher/pusher-php-server"`: `"7.2.0"` we didn't have this error in `Laravel 8.83` (previous version that was using `pusher-php-server` : 4)

Do you know if there are any incompatibilities in Laravel 9 with Pusher? Do you have any leads for an answer?

Thanks a lot in advence.

Comment: I know nothing about Laravel, but looking `api-.pusher.com` it seems like there should be a version in the subdomain maybe? Liike `api-v1`. Is it possible you missed a config option?